# How deep is a gravity well of a supermassive black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon, estimation

Just for the sake of curiosity I am trying to understand how far we should stay away from the black hole to avoid influence of its gravity on us.

In the first iteration I know about the 2nd and the 3rd cosmic speed that let you reach the orbit and leave it respectively. From another perspective we might look at this issue as a gravity well where we should escape from - get enough speed, pass some distance. It is all depends on the radius and the mass of the object, in our case a black hole. [the 2nd cosmic speed formula](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/78b611db1191aef406388a5fe1b621f26aff7539)

Going further I was trying to evaluate the mass of the 'average' black hole. Apparently, it was discovered black holes with intermediate-mass are the more rarest ones. There are three types of black holes and stellar black holes together with supermassive black holes prevalent in the discovered universe. [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate-mass_black_hole)

In such case let's take the supermassive black hole to evaluate the upper bound of the safe distance from the black hole without starting moving towards it.  If the mass of the supermassive black hole I have found out (~100 000 000 * 'the mass of the Sun'), the others necessary data takes more time.

Comment: Isn't this just asking for the radius of the event horizon?

Comment: Not, it is not. Even without reaching the event of horizon we will be within an influence of the black hole's gravity and without other forces applied to us we will be moving towards the black hole.

Comment: You are within the influence of the super massive black hole at the center of the Milky Way galaxy right now. In fact, you are trapped in an orbit around the thing.

Comment: Thank you for contribution, you are right. The more correct question I am trying to answer see in the comment to the @Andrew post.

Comment: @JoeDow Yes, the gravitational field has infinite range. For a Schwarzschild black hole there are no other length scales.

Comment: The spacelike radius of any black hole is zero, so the well is infinitely deep. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This brought to me a plenty amount of ideas and thoughts to think and play with, but to continue discuss them here will break platform policies. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravity doesn't have a finite range. In a Universe with just you and the black hole, if you do not take action to move away from the black hole or to orbit the black hole, given enough time it will pull you in no matter where you start from.

In the real Universe, there are more things than just you and one black hole. As a result, you experience pulls in different directions and don't fall toward one particular object unless the gravitational pull for that object is stronger than the accumulated gravitational effect of all other bodies in the Universe. Therefore there is no general way to answer your question without having a model of what other things are in the Universe, at least things that are close enough to the black hole that their influence competes with the black hole's.

If you do start falling into a black hole, you can either escape by accelerating away from the black hole, or reach a stable orbit by accelerating in a direction perpendicular to the line connecting you and the black hole. This is possible to do until you cross the event horizon, at which point you will inevitably hit the singularity. For a non-spinning black hole, the size of the event horizon is given in terms of the mass of the black hole via the [Schwarzschild radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_radius).

Comment: Thank you for bringing more clarity in this. It clarified the gravity force from the object is always here, the question which remains open is what is the distance where the gravity force of the black hole become small enough to start decreasing by exponent (power of gravity force \ distance)? It should be inversely proportional to the square of the distance between me and the black hole.

Comment: @JoeDow The inverse square law gets corrections which scale as powers of your distance to the black hole divided by the Schwarzschild radius. If your distance from the black hole is a lot larger than the Schwarzschild radius (say a factor of 10 or more), then these corrections are small and the inverse square law is approximately correct.

Comment: Thank you for correction, now I know it from you. Would you be able to figure out approximate the distance and the speed from the black hole with mass of 100 million masses of the Sun in the Universe where just me and this supermassive black hole?

Comment: Well up until the photon sphere you can have orbits with only a tangential component of velocity, anything less and there needs be a a component pointed outwards from the black hole.

Comment: @Triatticus I think you meant the Innermost Stable Circular Orbit (ISCO), which is different from the photon sphere and applies to massive particles. I swept that under the rug, but yes, you can't have *circular* orbits with radii smaller than the ISCO.

Comment: This brought to me a plenty amount of ideas and thoughts to think and play with, but to continue discuss them here will break platform policies. Thank you all for your help!